# what's a c++ equivalent of a generic?

Tags: java, c++, generics, object, polymorphism

suppose i'm implementing a polymorphic tree data structure that can take on data of any type...

```
Tree<Int> or Tree<String> or Tree<Object>
```

but I'm implementing it in C++....how would I specify that the tree can contain an arbitrary type similar to generics in Java

also is there an equivalent of Java's Object object in C++ in which all objects in C++ inherits Object

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot do that in java. All you can do is to make a tree of type `Object`. You would need dynamic typing to a much larger degree to implement what you described. It rather sounds like you want "Write once, then generate trees for arbitrary types.". Each tree itself is still monomorphic, can contain only Strings, or Ints, etc.

Comment: you actually can do that in java, besides of Tree<Int>. int is a primitive type, he should've used Tree<Integer>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nearest equivalent of Java's generic is template in C++. Its not equivalent as such, if strictly speaking. But that is what you've in C++. So to suit your need, you've to work a little bit so that you can write equivalent code in C++.

Here're few links to some  articles that compare C++ template with Java generics:

- [Java Generics and C++ Templates](http://drdobbs.com/184401818) (at Dr Dobbs)
- [Generics in C#, Java, and C++](http://www.artima.com/intv/generics2.html) (at artima.com)

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to have a single container that can contain anything, you could make the container's value type be [Boost Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/any.html).  But it sounds like what you're looking for is a homogenous container, and the template answers here make sense for that.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you use templates, in the form

```
template <typename T>
    class Tree {
        TreeNode<T> Root
        ...
    };
```

Templates aren't identical to generics, they offer a bit more flexibility (and more ability to shoot yourself in the foot). You can't constrain a template type parameter to be a subclass of a certain type for example. And C++ doesn't have strong type checking inside the template, which is where it can be easy to make a mess.

Comment: "a bit more flexbility" is a grose understatement. Templates form a turing complete meta language.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are C++ [templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/).

You can declare a templated class like:

```
template<class TType>
class AClass
{
private:
    TType *somePointer;
};
```

Classes do not derive from a common base in C++, like they do in languages like C# and Java.  The closest you'll get is a `void*`, but that throws all type-safety out the door and I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the language of generics: `Tree<Int>` or `Tree<String>` aren't supposed to hold objects of any type; they specifically hold integers or strings. Only `Tree<Object>` would be able to hold "any" type, but C++ doesn't have a concept equivalent to "object". You might be able to hold "any" type in your tree using [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/any.html) although I haven't used it myself.

Use C++ templates to hold a specific type:

```
template<typename T>
class Tree {
    ...
};
```

Usage:

```
Tree<int> treeOfInts;
```

Answer (score 0):

Templates.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Weird. If you were in Synergy (with Feng?) then we both worked in KWII probably.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, naive attempt at java's generics would be `Tree<void*>`. That's not very good and many people will replace that with the following:

```
class TreeBase { };
class TreeInt : public TreeBase { int i; };
```

And then use `Tree<TreeBase*>`. This lets you specify which types will be compatible with it. It's equivalent of the java's Object thing.

Yet another layer would be to have `Tree<Node> n;` with just simple `struct Node { TreeBase *b; };`

But since we're talking about trees, c++ has considerably better way to do that, since it's directly supported via the c++ classes:

```
class TreeNode { virtual ~TreeNode() { } };
class MyIntTreeNode : public TreeNode {
public:
    MyTreeNode(int i) : i(i) { }
    int i;
};
class MyStringTreeNode : public TreeNode {
public:
   MyStringTreeNode(string s) : s(s) { }
   string s;
};
class MyArrayTreeNode : public TreeNode {
public:
   MyArrayTreeNode(std::vector<TreeNode*> v) : v(v) { }
   std::vector<TreeNode*> v;
};
```

Creating the tree couldnt be easier, once necessary types are available:

```
int main() {
  MyIntTreeNode n1(10);
  MyStringTreeNode n2("abc");
  std::vector<TreeNode*> v;
  v.push_back(&n1);
  v.push_back(&n2);
  MyArrayTreeNode n3(v);
  algo(n3);
  }
```

This approach has the advantage that every treenode can have different behaviour. The downside is that it's slightly verbose.